# Failing to read configmap with kubernetes 1.17.4

Tags: kubernetes

My POD fails to read kubernetes configmap in a specific combination of software/versions:

Container: containerd
Kubernetes version: 1.17.4
docker base image: openjdk:8

When deploying the POD, I get:

```
Failed to get pod with name:[...]. You should look into this if things aren't working as you expect. Are you missing serviceaccount permissions?"
Operation: [get]  for kind: [...]  with name: [...]  in namespace: [...]  failed
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:221)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:177)
        --- 8< ---
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException: null
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:219)
        --- 8< ---
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:210)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I know that there are various reasons for this error, like serviaccount permissions. But this used to work for a long time. Only thing I have changed is to switch from baseimage `openjdk:8` to `openjdk:8-alpine`.

It works fine again when switching back to the alpine image. But alpine has some DNS issues resulting in slow connections.

Any idea, why this happens?

Comment: can you post the pod spec for the old and new one?

Comment: Sorry, which spec do you want to see, actually?

Comment: You mentioned that you just switched the base image, so the spec of the object with the new image and with the old one